# Engine replacement

Tags: honda

I have a Honda Odyssey Ex 2007 and the engine/motor has gone bad. It came with Vtec engine/motor. I consider replacing the engine/motor with iVtecVCM. Please I want to know if that can work normal. Can someone please, advise before I make a mistake. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There are a few questions on VTEC swaps on here. However, in most cases on Hondas where you are not replacing like engines, the answer is usually no. The problem is with the control systems. Unless you completely replace everything (engine, wiring, ECU), you will not get the result you desire.

Comment: I did comment earlier to have a look at similar posts on here that may help...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm now guided from making a mistake. Thanks once more.